# How to pass Rails variable to AngularJS config

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Angular app config I have:

> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Custom-Auth-Token'] = ____;
>   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Custom-Auth-Signature'] = ____;

These headers are necessary in order to make ANY API requests to the Rails backend server.

On my Rails backend, I'm using Sorcery and have access to `current_user.authentication_token` in my controller/views. I thus need to pass this to the angular config.js.erb. Is this even possible?

Another issue I have is that the auth-token will then be hashed with an app secret (this is only available on the Rails server and shouldn't ever be seen in the JavaScript), which becomes the auth-signature. How do I perform this action on the rails side, then pass this to Angular's config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put this information in data attribute of a HTML tag. From the Angular app in your frontend you just have to fetch this tag with his id and get the data from it.

Comment: Thanks, works great! I really wish there was a way to pass a rails variable directly though.